# Passing array from Controller to view in codeigniter

Tags: php, mongodb

hi I m new in mongodb and codeigniter I have try to make simple CRUD operation in
mongodb and php codeigniter I m trying to pass my array from Controller to view but it could not be done it gives an error 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: user_list

Filename: views/show_user.php

Line Number: 15

here is my code for Controller

```
class user extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct();
         //loading  the mongodb library
         $this->load->model('mongo_model');
    }

   //index where the controller starts
    public function index() 
    {
        $collection = $this->mongo_model->selectCollectiondb();
        $collection= iterator_to_array($collection);
        foreach ($collection as $users)
        {
        $data['_id']=$users['_id'];
        $data['firstname']=$users['firstname'];
        $data['lastname']=$users['lastname'];
        $data['email']=$users['email'];
        $data['password']=$users['password'];
        }
        print_r($data);
        $this->load->view('show_user',$data);
    }
}
```

Code for view is

```
<?php 
print_r($user_list);
exit();
<?php }?>
```

Comment: here is my model code
 public  function selectCollectiondb()
        {   
             $query=$this->mongo_db->db->selectCollection('myfirstCollection');
              return $result=$query->find();  
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing proper array to variable to to view.

CodeIgniter passes variables/arrays from controller to view in the form of a parent array.

In your case, `$data`.

The keys of `$data` will become variables in view appended with `$` symbol.

Virtually, in views, `$data` is [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) ed.

Corrected code:

```
public function index()  {
  $collection = $this->mongo_model->selectCollectiondb();
  $collection= iterator_to_array($collection);
  $user_list = array();
  foreach ($collection as $users) {
    $data['_id']=$users['_id'];
    $data['firstname']=$users['firstname'];
    $data['lastname']=$users['lastname'];
    $data['email']=$users['email'];
    $data['password']=$users['password'];
    $user_list[$users['_id']]['firstname'] = $users['firstname'];
    $user_list[$users['_id']]['lastname'] = $users['lastname'];
    $user_list[$users['_id']]['email'] = $users['email'];
    $user_list[$users['_id']]['password'] = $users['password'];
  }
  $data['user_list'] = $user_list;
  print_r($data);
  $this->load->view('show_user',$data);
}
```

Comment: thanks @pupil for reply but I got the way  to send the array
   $collection = $this->mongo_model->selectCollectiondb();
        $collection= iterator_to_array($collection); 
        $data['user_list']=$collection;
        print_r($data);
        $this->load->view('show_user',$data);

Answer (score 0):

There is not any $user_list variable defined in controller code.

print $data in your view.

```
  <?php 
   print_r($data);
   exit();
  ?>
```